# How to publish the second WCF services in a subdirectory?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7

I have a published WCF service in the root directory (VPS, IIS 7). It has `Service1.svc` file and `web.config` file.
I would like to publish another WCF service on the same IIS in a subfolder (let's assume that the subfolder's name is `subservice2`). This another WCF service also has `Service2.svc` file and `web.config` file.
Where should I put the files of the second WCF service to make it work properly?
Do I need to set or change any settings in IIS?
My first attempt was simply to create a subfolder `subservice2` and to put all files of the second WCF service there, but this didn't work (I get `Server Error in '/' Application.` if I try to access `mysiteaddress/subservice2/Service2.svc`).

Comment: Doesn't work how? Just thinking offhand it should without any iis changes.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have added the details of "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Combine the two .svc endpoints into just one project, update the endpoint configurations in web.config, then deploy them together. This may not be possible if the two projects have separate deployment or maintenance schedules.
2. Since web.configs are inherited within the same web application in IIS, you can spend some significant time trying to iron out all the configuration conflicts. This is possible, but it's messy and complicated.
3. Create a new website in IIS and use host headers to direct traffic to the correct site. Deploy the new service to the new site. This may also have configuration problems if you plan to use SSL. Unless you are using a wildcard cert, the IP and Port combination must be unique.

Option #1 is easily your best solution if you can overcome the project merge.

Comment: In the third option (it is more preferable for me) what host header should I set? I tried `mywebsitename/subservice2`, but got an error message that using symbols like `/` is prohibited there...

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do it that way. You would have to set headers for both sites, and one would be `subdomain1.domain.com` and the other would be `subdomain2.domain.com`.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up this article, which might help you if you choose to stick with Option #2: http://www.dondraper.com/2010/02/how-to-stop-inheritance-of-webconfig-files/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just bind services to different ports? Programmatically, that's equivalent to:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
Binding wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding( );
Binding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding( );
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyContract),wsBinding,
   "http://localhost:8000/MyService");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyContract),tcpBinding,
   "net.tcp://localhost:8001/MyService");
host.Open();

ServiceHost OtherHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyOtherService));
Binding wsBinding2 = new WSHttpBinding( );
OtherHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyOtherContract),wsBinding2,
   "http://localhost:8002/MyOtherService");
OtherHost.Open();
```

http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/WCF_Essentials%E2%80%94Programmatic_Endpoint_Configuration